# How to go back to upper position in a program

Tags: java

I am trying to make node based big integer calculator in Java, and I want to re print the menu of calculator after operations. I thought of using goto but it gives error saying goto byte expected.

I am new in java, so can any one help me with the below demo code-

```
up:
        System.out.println("YOU HAVE FOLLOWING CHOICES : ");
        System.out.println("1. ADDITION");
        System.out.println("2. SUBTRACTION ");

int i=s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("ENTER FIRST NUMBER ");
        int a=s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("ENTER SECOND NUMBER ");
        int b=s.nextInt();
        int result = 0;
switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                result=a+b;
                break;
            case 2:
                result=a-b;
                break;
default:
    goto up;
}
```

Thank you, I just want to reprint the menu.

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: @PhilipVaughn I felt that too, but it's still a question nevertheless :P

Comment: @PhilipVaughn: Anything wrong on the need of help with a homework?

Comment: other than the fact you're suppose to be learning that stuff in your class nah i suppose not

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple while-loop for that. Maybe create a boolean as the running condition and set it to false, when the user types something else than 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support **`goto`**, as it is a **[reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)**.

Also, IMHO, using **`goto`** is [**not** a great way to write a program](http://xkcd.com/292/).

A better approach would be to write a function which displays the menu and call that function whenever you want. Or just use a do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't use `goto` as it doesn't really fit into the Object-Oriented concept (I faced the same problem years ago when I made the switch from Basic). So you'll have to reconsider your code's logic to implement a loop of some sort.

Something like:

```
do {
    // add an exit option to the menu
    System.out.println("YOU HAVE FOLLOWING CHOICES : ");
    System.out.println("1. ADDITION");
    System.out.println("2. SUBTRACTION ");
    System.out.println("3. EXIT");

    // continue with the same logic you had before

} while (i !=3)
```

I hope that helps.

note: if you lookup the keyword `goto` in Java documentation, you'll see that it's reserved but it doesn't do anything. They probably reserved it as a placeholder for these situations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to look at "goto" in a java environment, using your code as the example:

```
public void addUp() {
    System.out.println("YOU HAVE FOLLOWING CHOICES : ");
    System.out.println("1. ADDITION");
    System.out.println("2. SUBTRACTION ");

    int i=s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("ENTER FIRST NUMBER ");
    int a=s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("ENTER SECOND NUMBER ");
    int b=s.nextInt();
    int result = 0;
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
            result=a+b;
            break;
        case 2:
            result=a-b;
            break;
        default: addUp();

    }
}
```

Comment: WARNING: This is very very bad practice... You'll keep adding to the runtime stack using this recursive way. A loop of some sort is much safer my friend.

Comment: Yes. I would never code this way, however, it gives an illusion of a goto in that you see where you are calling yourself....

Comment: In other words, you see the concept, which he is looking for something like that in Java. Here is the closest thing to it. NEVER DO THIS, lol